# How to resolve circular dependencies?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, circular-dependency

My question is about a compiler for any language that supports circular function dependencies, it doesn't matter which language. The language is compiled to machine code/byte code, the compiler doesn't piggyback on a compiler for some other language.

What are the usual ways of dealing with circular dependencies?

Comment: In what regard? Semantic analysis, code generation or linking?

Comment: @rightføld Both code generation and linking